# What's wrong with my use of ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using **ui-router** and the view below accesses the controller using the **'Controller As'** syntax. I'm adding the 'invalid' class onto the **'shift'-radios** container. When form loads you can see both validation **required** messages (for **requestDate** and **shift**). When **requestDate** and **shift** are set validation messages disappear. Form's **`$valid`** is true. The only problem is that the **'invalid'** class on the **radio-wrapper** div stays.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="_form.$valid && formCtrl.getFormData()" name="_form">
    <div class="datepicker-wrapper clearfix">
        <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
            <input required ng-model="formCtrl.requestDate" name="requestDate" type="text" />
        </datepicker>                       
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="_form.requestDate.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">Введите дату</div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-wrapper clearfix" ng-class="{invalid: _form.shift.$error}">
        <div ng-repeat="shift in formCtrl.shifts" class="item half-width pull-left">
            <label for="<% shift.name %>">
                <input required ng-model="formCtrl.currentShift" 
                       name="shift" 
                       ng-value="shift" 
                       id="<% shift.name %>" 
                       type="radio" />
                <span class="text"><span ng-bind="shift.text"></span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="_form.shift.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">Укажите смену</div>
    </div>
    <!-- other inputs... -->
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `ng-class="{'invalid': _form.shift.$error}"` instead of `ng-class="{invalid: _form.shift.$error}"` (**invalid** simple quoted)?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Single quotes around the class name are only required if the class name contains a dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use the `$invalid` property, which is a boolean, instead of the `$error` property, which is a hash.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-class` definition is checking the wrong property of the form controller.  You are checking the truthyness of `_form.shift.$error`.  This object will always exist, even if there are no validation errors.  When you don't have any errors, the value of `_form.shift.$error` is empty object `{}` which is truthy.

You should instead check the `_form.shift.$invalid` property which will properly update whether there are any problems with that form field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `_form.shift`.  The input `shift` is declared inside an ng-repeat so it is a property on the `_form`.

To fix you could for example, move your `ng-class` inside the ng-repeat and reference the shift using `ng-form` to create a sub-grouping:

```
<div ng-repeat="shift in formCtrl.shifts" ng-form='nestedShiftForm'>
    <div ng-class="{invalid: nestedShiftForm.shift.$error}">
        <input name="shift" />
```